# issue executing many queues at same time php

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, pdo, queue

i am running a game based on php. that is based on queues
each task is stored in db table queues with type and end time
if time is now , then it should be executed directly .

the issue is that when we have a lot of tasks at same time , then time becomes negative and this is so bad ..

it is a timing game , delay is a big issue

we use vps server , 4cpu , 8 rams

this is the responsible code :

```
   public function processQueue($type = 3, $playerId = 0)
    {
        global $gameConfig;
        $this->load_model('Mutex', 'mutex');
        $this->mutex->releaseOnTimeout();
        if ($this->mutex->lock()) {
            $this->processTaskQueue($type, $playerId);
            // to make it weekly put "/2" after it 
            $row = db::get_row("SELECT gs.cur_week w1, CEIL((TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(gs.start_date))) w2 FROM g_settings gs");
            if (($row['w2'] - $row['w1']) >= 1) {
                db::query("UPDATE g_settings gs SET gs.cur_week=:cur", array(
                    'cur' => intval($row['w2'])
                ));
                $allP = db::get_all("SELECT p.id FROM p_players p WHERE 1 ");
                $Ids2 = "";
                foreach($allP as $Ids)
                {
                    $Ids2 .= ($Ids2 == "" ) ? $Ids['id'] : ",".$Ids['id'];
                }
                $Ids2 = "(".$Ids2.")";
                db2::query("UPDATE p_players p SET p.gold_num=p.gold_num+:gold WHERE p.is_active=1 and p.id IN $Ids2",array('gold' =>200));
                $this->setWeeklyMedals(intval($row['w2']));
            }
            $this->mutex->release();
        }
    }

public function processTaskQueue($type, $playerId)
    {
        $p_type = QS_ACCOUNT_DELETE . ',' . QS_MERCHANT_GO . ',' . QS_MERCHANT_BACK . ',' . QS_WAR_REINFORCE . ',' . QS_WAR_ATTACK . ',' . QS_WAR_ATTACK_PLUNDER . ',' . QS_WAR_ATTACK_SPY . ',' . QS_CREATEVILLAGE . ',' . QS_TROOP_TRAINING . ',' . QS_SITE_RESET . ',' . QS_CROP_DELETE . ',' . QS_ARTEFACTS_RAISE .','. QS_TATAR_RAISE;
        if ($type == 1) {
            $expr = "((q.player_id=" . $playerId . " AND q.proc_type!=" . QS_TROOP_TRAINING . ") OR q.proc_type IN (" . $p_type . "))";
        } elseif ($type == 2) {
            $expr = "(q.player_id=" . $playerId . " OR q.proc_type IN (" . $p_type . "))";
        } else {
            $expr = "q.proc_type!=" . QS_TROOP_TRAINING;
        }
        $result = db::get_all("SELECT  q.id, q.player_id, q.village_id, q.to_player_id, q.to_village_id, q.proc_type, q.building_id, q.proc_params, q.threads, q.execution_time, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),q.end_date) remainingTimeInSeconds FROM p_queue q WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),(q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) SECOND)) <= 0 AND $expr ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),(q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) SECOND)) ASC");
        foreach ($result as $resultRow) {
            $remain = $resultRow['remainingTimeInSeconds'];
            if ($remain < 0) {
                $remain = 0;
            }
            $resultRow['threads_completed_num'] = $resultRow['execution_time'] <= 0 ? $resultRow['threads'] : floor(($resultRow['threads'] * $resultRow['execution_time'] - $remain) / $resultRow['execution_time']);
            if ($this->processTask($resultRow)) {
                unset($result);
                $this->processQueue($type, $playerId);
                break;
            }
        }
        unset($result);

    }
```

we need help , i am willing to pay as well if needed ..

Comment: *then time becomes negative* ??? I can imagine negative time interval but not negative time... how this looks like really?

Comment: Hello , i meant its been delayed